# Highcharts cannot reload multiple series chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts and I have no problem reloading data for single series charts.  However, I cannot seem to update multiple series charts.  Anytime I try, It just renders blank.  Here is my sample code:

```
for (i=0; i < response_data.line_data.length; i++) {
    line_chart.series[i].setData(response_data.line_data[i], false);
}
line_chart.redraw();
```

I know the data is correct because I used the same function to create the chart in the first place.

Help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score -1):

Please take look at my example where update series works properly,

```
$('#button').click(function() {
var newSeries = [],
    i;
newSeries[0] = [5,4,3,2,1];
newSeries[1] = [10,9,8,7,6];
newSeries[2] = [12,2,1,12,3];

var len = newSeries.length;

for(i = 0;i<len;i++)
{
    chart.series[i].setData(newSeries[i],false);
}

chart.redraw();
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/ebuTs/13919/

Comment: Sebastian..I know everything works in your example, but mine still doesn't work.  The only difference is that my data has an [x,y] component to it. So instead of newSeries[0] = [5,4,3..], I have newSeries[0] = [[1,5],[2,4],[3,3]]. Would that make a difference?